# How to convert this function to async generator

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I am trying to build an async generator, but I couldn't find any resources or figure out how to do it.

I am still getting the same error

> TypeError: 'async for' requires an object with **aiter** method, got
> coroutine

I read a not understandable for pep from 2016 and I am really confused.

Basically what I am trying to do is to schedule multiple coroutines and when one of them finishes I yield a value so I can process it immediately after the result comes without waiting for every result.

But I couldn't figure out this so I decided I will assume that coroutines will finish in the order they were created and I still have a lot of problems

I am looking for some solution for either yielding coroutines result in one after another or reacting to the first finished coroutine

Thanks in advance for any tips, resources, examples, and solutions :)

```
async def get_from_few_pages(
    self,
    max_pages: int = 0,
):
    pages = [
        asyncio.ensure_future(
            asyncio.get_running_loop().create_task(self.extract_data_from_page(i))
        )
        for i in range(max_pages)
    ]

    for coroutine in pages:
        await asyncio.gather(coroutine)
        yield coroutine.result()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create an async generator, you create an `async def` with a `yield` inside, much like your code does. In fact, your code looks like something that should actually work, although imperfectly, so I don't know why you're getting the error you quote.

However, there are issues with your code:

- it will always yield the coroutines in the order they are given, not in the order in which they complete - but they *will* run in parallel.
- you don't need both `ensure_future()` and `create_task()`, `create_task()` is sufficient
- you don't `asyncio.gather()` to await a single thing, it's for when you have more than one thing to await in parallel

To get a generator that yields awaitables as they complete, you can use `asyncio.wait(return_when=FIRST_COMPLETED)`, like this:

```
async def get_from_few_pages(self, max_pages):
    pending = [asyncio.create_task(self.extract_data_from_page(i))
               for i in range(max_pages)]
    while pending:
        done, pending = await asyncio.wait(pending, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
        for fut in done:
            yield fut.result()
```

Comment: Works by with await before asyncio.wait